# Addition/subtraction of Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have this array.

```rb
items = [
  {
    amount: 100,
    add: true
  },
  {
    amount: 50,
    add: false
  },
  {
    amount: 100,
    add: true
  }
]
```

What I want to do is add the amount if `add` is `true` and subtract it if `add` is `false`.

This code uses an extra `total` variable.

```rb
total = 0
items.each do |item|
  if item[:add]
    total += item[:amount]
  else
    total -= item[:amount]
  end
end
```

A one-liner code.

```rb
items.sum { |item| item[:add] ? item[:amount] : -item[:amount] }
```

I wonder if there is a better implementation for this problem. Is the one-liner readable enough?

Comment: The one-line solution looks readable enough to me. A shorter version could be using keyword arguments: `items.sum { |add:, amount:| add ? amount : -amount }`

Comment: @AlterLagos I have been doing that with JavaScript. I don't know you can do that in Ruby. I can use that knowledge more in the future. Thanks.